# How to best get around CouchDB's non-RDBMS limitations

Tags: nosql, couchdb, relational-database

We have two document 'types': `Post` and `User`:

Typical post:

```
{
   "_id": "3847345345",
   "Schema": "Post",
   "Text": "Hello World! This is a post!",
   "IsFeatured": true,
   "UserID": "12345345345234234"
}
```

Typical user:

```
{
   "_id": "12345345345234234",
   "Schema": "User",
   "Username": "georgepowell"
   "PostIds": ["3847345345","5135345345","9987453236", ... ]
}
```

On a web page that displays a `Post`, the `Username` for that post (plus whatever other changable information about that user) is displayed alongside the post. Similar to SO:
[image: user info]

This is a typical example of a situation where an SQL JOIN would be perfect, but of course CouchDB doesn't support anything like that. Instead we could make a view that indexes both `User` documents and `Post` documents on a `Post`'s `_id`. Like this:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.Schema = 'Post') {
        emit([doc._id, 0], null);
    } else if (doc.Schema = 'User') {
        foreach (string id in doc.PostIds) // not javascript I know. shhh
            emit([id, 1], null);
    }
}
```

which works well, as we can efficiently retrieve all the information we need given a single `Post`'s `_id`.

However, if I want to create a view that lists all the posts where `IsFeatured == true` along with all the user data, I get stuck!

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.Schema = 'Post' && doc.IsFeatured) {
        emit([doc._id, 0], null);
    } else if (doc.Schema = 'User') {
        foreach (string id in doc.PostIds)
            emit([id, 1], null); // I can't check if the post is featured!
    }
}
```

Have I reached the limit of CouchDB for relational data? or is this kind of indexing possible in CouchDB?

Comment: It is no mystery that there are things single SQL query can do, single view cannot. Searching in SO posts will show you lots of problematic queries. You should not stick to single view "rule". Although it is obviously better to reduce client-server RPCs, the world is not going to fall apart because of one more request ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a different technology there are trade-offs.  And sometimes although things look like they will take more resources (an extra request) in the short-run it can be inconsequential, and in the long-run may give significant scalability, if you need that sort of thing.

CouchDB can handle a lot of different "databases" at the same time, which you can think of as different model spaces.  So with the same running instance of CouchDB you could have `/users` and `/posts`.  This requires absolutely no additional work on the part of configuration or performance of CouchDB.

This can make your map code more straight forward as you then don't need to have the 'Schema' field and be incorporating it into every map function.

Also, you can (and should) have multiple different map/reduce pairs in a given design view.  This is important because if you have two different document "Schema"s `emit(doc.id, doc.val)`  how can you tell which is which for reduce purposes.

A more CouchDB idiomatic way to look at your data would be that you don't save the post_ids on the user.  Just the UserID on the Posts, then have a map something like the following for Posts:

```
(doc) ->
  emit([doc.user_id, doc.isFeatured], null);
  emit([doc.isFeatured, doc.createdAt], doc.user_id);
```

Then a request to the view API with arguments like `?start_key=['12345345345234234']&end_key=['12345345345234234',{}]` would get all their posts.

Where one with `?key=['12345345345234234', 1]` would just get their featured posts.

The second emit also gives you ability to quickly get all of the posts that are featured across the whole system sorted by date -- with who made them if you want that data, without getting the whole of the posts sent down the pipe.